# Postfix - dkim warnings

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-14.04, dkim

I just set up DKIM on my server (OS: Ubuntu 14.04) and by checking via different dkim online checkers (eg. http://dkimcore.org/tools/keycheck.html) everything is fine, so it means that my domain records and postfix are probably configured properly, because I can send outgoing mails.

But in my `/var/log/mail.log` file there are some unwanted warnings:

`postfix/smtpd[22751]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8891: Connection refused`

What does it stand for and how to fix it? Is there anyone able to help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question, in your Postfix configuration, you've probably defined something like this:

```
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

Now, considering your error message, there is no service listening on 8891.

This should be your OpenDKIM - or maybe spamassassin, or amavis depends how you've set it up. Either there is a typo setting that port, or your service isn't listening on localhost (check for other interfaces), or the service in question is not running.

Whatever services you've setup configuring DKIM signature: make sure they are running:

```
service (opendkim|amavis|spamassassin) (status|restart)
```

Please update your initial post including your Postfix configuration (`/etc/postfix/main.cf`), for more details on what to check.

Answer (score 0):

The "milter service" is a pass-off from Postfix to run messages through an anti-spam (spamassassin) or anti-virus (amavis, etc) scanner before sending out and/or delivering to Dovecot/etc. to be sent ot a users in-box.

That "can't connect" message means that your milter service is either not running or it isn't running on the port that you've specified.

Check in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to see exactly what the milter service is supposed to be providing, and then look at the configuration for that thing.  Or just post your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file (properly formatted please)